# Stackoverflow Exception while using a Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, console, stack-overflow

I am getting a stack overflow exception while using the linq statement below

`var dbUsers = context.users.Where(ad => userIDList.Any(up => up == ad.UserID)).ToList();`

The users the list of users from the database using entity framework.
userIDList is a list of userids in string format.
I am trying to get all users from the database that have the same userid as in the list userIDList so I can make changes to those users.
The list is large (23k). Could that be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

> The list is large (23k). Could that be the issue?

It is definitely an issue. SQL does not support such big query and worse fact that EF is trying to create predicate for such big list and fails.
Also this query should be simplified

```
var dbUsers = context.users
   .Where(ad => userIDList.Contains(ad.UserID)).ToList();
```

But I don't think that this will help, only temporary table can help in such situation.

Since I don't know other solutions, leaving here sample using [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore) extension (disclaimer I'm author of this extension) and you can return back when all other solutions will fail.

```
class IdHolder
{
   [Column] public int Id;
}

...

var ids = userIDList.Select(id => new IdHolder { Id = id });

using (var l2db = context.CreateLinqToDBConnection())
using (var temp = l2db.CreateTemporaryTable("#UserIds", ids))
{
    var query = 
      from t in temp
      join u in context.users on t.Id equals u.UserId
      select u;

   var dbUsers = query.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Yes the large number of records was the issue. I was able to make it work by breaking the list down into smaller blocks.